# JSON array to JSON with emebeded arrays parsing problems

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

So I have a JSON structure which I have to parse to a different one. I did it but I see that one of the nodes has wrong value.

If BodyId = value and TrId = null and TdId = null then Body Id is a parent node.
If BodyId = value and TrId = value and TdId = null then TrId is a child node of the parent node.
If BodyId = value and TrId = value and TdId = value then TdId is a child node of the previous child node.

BodyId>TrId>TdId

Here is JSON and parsing:

```
var data = [
  {
    "BodyId": 1,
    "TrId": null,
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "BodyId1",
    "Status": "Ok"
  }, {
    "BodyId": 2,
    "TrId": null,
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "BodyId2",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 3,
    "TrId": null,
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "BodyId3",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 1,
    "TrId": 1,
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "TrId1",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 1,
    "TrId": 2,
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "TrId2",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 2,
    "TrId": 1,
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "TrId1",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 2,
    "TrId": 2,
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "TrId2",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 3,
    "TrId": 1,
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "TrId1",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 3,
    "TrId": 2,
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "TrId2",
    "Status": "Ok"   
  }, 
    {
    "BodyId": 3,
    "TrId": 3,
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "TrId3",
    "Status": "Ok"   
  }, 
    {
    "BodyId": 1,
    "TrId": 1,
    "TdId": 1,
    "Title": "TdId1",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 1,
    "TrId": 1,
    "TdId": 2,
    "Title": "TdId2",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 2,
    "TrId": 1,
    "TdId": 1,
    "Title": "TdId1",
    "Status": "Ok"   
  }, {
    "BodyId": 2,
    "TrId": 1,
    "TdId": 2,
    "Title": "TdId2",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 2,
    "TrId": 2,
    "TdId": 1,
    "Title": "TdId1",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }, {
    "BodyId": 3,
    "TrId": 3,
    "TdId": 1,
    "Title": "TdId1",
    "Status": "Ok"    
  }];


          var json = [];
var tdArray = [];        
          for(key=0; key < data.length; key++)
          {
            var singleBodyId = null;
            var singleTrId = null;
            var singleTd = null;

            if(data[key].TrId === null)
            { 
              //parent ID  
              json.push(data[key]);
              singleBodyId = data[key].BodyId;
                var trArray = []; 

              for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
              {
                  if(data[i].BodyId === singleBodyId && data[i].TrId !== null && data[i].TdId === null)
                  {  
                      //child array of parent ID
                      trArray.push(data[i]);
                  }
                  for(w=0;w<trArray.length;w++)
                  {
                      if(data[i].BodyId === trArray[w].BodyId && data[i].TrId == trArray[w].TrId && data[i].TdId !== null)
                      {
                          //child array of child array
                          tdArray.push(data[i]);
                      }
                  }
              }
              for(q = 0; q < json.length; q++ )
              { 
                if(json[q].BodyId === singleBodyId)
                {
                    json[q].TrId = trArray;

                    for(t=0;t<json[q].TrId.length;t++)
                    {      
                        for(c=0;c<tdArray.length;c++)
                        {                    
                            if(tdArray[c].BodyId === json[q].TrId[t].BodyId && tdArray[c].TrId === json[q].TrId[t].TrId)
                            {
                                json[q].TrId[t].TdId = tdArray[c];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
              }
            }
          }

document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json);
<p id="print"></p>
```

Here is the output of this parsing, I added the comments where values are wrong. [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/luqo/ty20ks5j/)

```
[{
    "BodyId": 1,
    "TrId": [{
        "BodyId": 1,
        "TrId": 1,
        "TdId": {
            "BodyId": 1,
            "TrId": 1,
            "TdId": 2,       //this should be "TdId": 1
            "Title": "TdId2", //this should be "Title": 1
            "Status": "Ok"
        },
        "Title": "TrId1",
        "Status": "Ok"
    },                 
    {
        "BodyId": 1,
        "TrId": 2,        
        "TdId": null,     //this should be "TdId": 2
        "Title": "TrId2", //this should be  "Title": "TdId2"
        "Status": "Ok"
    }],
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "BodyId1",
    "Status": "Ok"
},             //the whole "TrId": 2 is missing and the rest of the JSON is repeating the same errors
{
    "BodyId": 2,
    "TrId": [{
        "BodyId": 2,
        "TrId": 1,
        "TdId": {
            "BodyId": 2,
            "TrId": 1,
            "TdId": 2,        
            "Title": "TdId2", 
            "Status": "Ok"
        },
        "Title": "TrId1",
        "Status": "Ok"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 2,
        "TrId": 2,            
        "TdId": {
            "BodyId": 2,
            "TrId": 2,        
            "TdId": 1,        
            "Title": "TdId1",
            "Status": "Ok"
        },
        "Title": "TrId2",
        "Status": "Ok"
    }],
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "BodyId2",
    "Status": "Ok"
},
{
    "BodyId": 3,
    "TrId": [{
        "BodyId": 3,
        "TrId": 1,
        "TdId": null,
        "Title": "TrId1",
        "Status": "Ok"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 3,
        "TrId": 2,
        "TdId": null,
        "Title": "TrId2",
        "Status": "Ok"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 3,
        "TrId": 3,
        "TdId": {
            "BodyId": 3,
            "TrId": 3,
            "TdId": 1,
            "Title": "TdId1",
            "Status": "Ok"
        },
        "Title": "TrId3",
        "Status": "Ok"
    }],
    "TdId": null,
    "Title": "BodyId3",
    "Status": "Ok"
}]
```

I would appreciate pointing me where I have mistakes !
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Added some more info hopefully this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess I will post an answer for my own question, thanks for help guys :)

If somebody need it, this code works well.
There is a place for upgrades i.e.: instead of using delete obj it's probably better to use "splice" but for some reasons it didn't work for me so I used delete and then I created new array without null values which occurred after using delete.

```
var body = [];
var tr = [];
var dataTmp = [];

for(key=0; key < data.length; key++)
{
    if(data[key].TrId === null)
    {    
        data[key].TrId = [];
        body.push(data[key]);
        delete data[key];
    } 
}
for(key=0; key < data.length; key++)
{
    if(data[key] != null)
    {
        dataTmp.push(data[key]);
    } 
}
data = dataTmp;
dataTmp = [];

for(key=0; key < data.length; key++)
{
    if(data[key].TrId !== null && data[key].TdId === null)
    {
        tr.push(data[key]);
        delete data[key];
    } 
}
for(key=0; key < data.length; key++)
{
    if(data[key] != null)
    {
        dataTmp.push(data[key]);
    } 
}
data = dataTmp;

for(key=0; key<body.length; key++)
{
    for(i=0;i<tr.length;i++)
    { 
        if(body[key].BodyId === tr[i].BodyId)
        {   
            tr[i].TdId = [];
            body[key].TrId.push(tr[i]);
        }
    }
}
for(key=0;key<body.length; key++)
{
    for(i=0; i<body[key].TrId.length; i++)
    {
        for(k=0; k<data.length; k++)
        {
            if(body[key].TrId[i].BodyId === data[k].BodyId && body[key].TrId[i].TrId === data[k].TrId)
            {
                body[key].TrId[i].TdId.push(data[k]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(body);
```